# jQuery doesn't seem to be finding nested class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looping through several instances of HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class="matchup-container">
    <div class="gamequestion">
        <strong>NBA: Who will WIN this matchup?</strong>
    </div>
    <table class="mg-gametableQ">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="mg-column1 start">
                    <div class="matchupDate">
                        <span class="startTime">11:00 AM</span>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="mg-column3 opponents  ">
                    <span>
                        <strong>
                            <a>Team</a>: Win
                        </strong>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="mg-column1 start">
                    <div class="matchupDate">
                        <span class="startTime">11:00 AM</span>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="mg-column3 opponents  ">
                    <span>
                        <strong>
                            <a>Team</a>: Win
                        </strong>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

There are several `matchup-container` divs to loop through, so I'm using `.each()` to do that. Then I want to loop through each `mg-column3` inside that div, so I use `.each()` again. Finally, I want to pull the text inside the `<a>` (in this case, "Team"), and append that inside the `mg-column3` div. My jQuery code is here:

```
$('.matchup-container').each(function() {
    var title = $.trim($(this).find('.gamequestion').text());

    $(this).find('.mg-column3').each(function () {
        if (isStraightUp(title))
        {
            var teams = getStraightUpTeams(this);
            $(this).append('<span class=odds-favorite>' + teams[0] + '</span>');
        }
    });
});

function isStraightUp (title)
{
    return true;
}

function getStraightUpTeams(matchup)
{
    var teams = [];

    teams[0] = $(matchup).find("a")[0].text();
    teams[1] = $(matchup).find("a")[1].text();

    return teams;
}
```

But nothing happens. The Chrome dev tools tell me that I can't call `.text()` on an undefined element, so everything crashes. But I can't figure out why the jQuery isn't grabbing the text inside the `<a>` tags that I want. Here's a [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/68N7D/16/) Can anyone help?

Comment: Your `mg-column3` elements only contain a single `a` each.  Why are you trying to access 2?  The 2nd doesn't exist.

Comment: @JamesMontagne just realized that myself, and fixed it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$(matchup)` return a jQuery object, you need to use jQuery method like **[.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)** or **[:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)** selector instead:

```
teams[0] = $(matchup).find("a").eq(0).text();
teams[1] = $(matchup).find("a").eq(1).text();
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/68N7D/18/)**

or:

```
teams[0] = $(matchup).find("a:eq(0)").text();
teams[1] = $(matchup).find("a:eq(1)").text();
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/68N7D/17/)**

Comment: thanks, this works! i'll accept this answer when i can because you were first.

Comment: use `.eq()` over `:eq()` every single time. way, way faster.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea I've added the demo with `.eq()` :)

Answer (score 1):

> Use .eq() in Jquery.

```
function getStraightUpTeams(matchup)
{
    var teams = [];

    teams[0] = $(matchup).find("a").eq(0).text();
    teams[1] = $(matchup).find("a").eq(1).text();

    return teams;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in `getStraightUpTeams`. Look at your console to see the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Property 'text' of object [object
>   HTMLAnchorElement] is not a function

You are trying to call a method `text` in a dom element reference which does not have such a method, you need to use jQuery wrapper to call the method `.text()`

```
function getStraightUpTeams(matchup) {
    var teams = [],
        $as = $(matchup).find("a");

    teams[0] = $as.eq(0).text();
    teams[1] = $as.eq(1).text();

    return teams;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/35ZR6/)